# Preview xml layout file without build project android studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I have big project in android studio and I can't build it because of lot of error!!!
I want just see preview of some XML so there is any way to see them without build completed successfully!!
except movie file to another project and see them ..!

My XML have some custom views. and custom views class have't any Error!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/recorder_help"
            android:paddingStart="14dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:paddingEnd="14dp"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/btn_menu_more"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgAbout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/about_margin_right"
            android:contentDescription="@string/about_title"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/normal_widget_padding"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/about_padding_top"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/normal_widget_padding"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/about_padding_top"
            android:src="@drawable/btn_about" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/speech_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/network_layout"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/record_mode_dictation"
            android:textColor="@color/recorder_text_color"
            android:textSize="@dimen/record_mode_text_size"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <com.soundrecorder.widget.frequencyview.SoundWave
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:visibility="invisible" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Maybe use design tab at the bottom of the editor window (i know that it is not a real device but it gets the job done)

Comment: you can't see preview of XML until build project completed successfully!(text tab preview and design tab both)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Udacity visualizer](https://labs.udacity.com/android-visualizer/) to preview XML layout files.

But not all features are available like `Gravity` or `layoutDirection`.